# How to delete all files under a specified directory with PHP?

Tags: php, file-io

I think the title is clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
$dir = '/some/path/to/delete/';//note the trailing slashes

$dh = opendir($dir);
while($file = readdir($dh))
{
    if(!is_dir($file))
    {
        @unlink($dir.$file);
    }
}
closedir($dh);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function Delete($path)
{
    if (is_dir($path) === true)
    {
        $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
                Delete(realpath($path) . '/' . $file);
        }

        return rmdir($path);
    }

    else if (is_file($path) === true)
    {
        return unlink($path);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: this will also delete the specified directory

Answer (score 1):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php.
You will find many functions in the comments that does what you need

One example:

```
function unlinkRecursive($dir, $deleteRootToo)
{
    if(!$dh = @opendir($dir))
    {
        return;
    }
    while (false !== ($obj = readdir($dh)))
    {
        if($obj == '.' || $obj == '..')
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (!@unlink($dir . '/' . $obj))
        {
            unlinkRecursive($dir.'/'.$obj, true);
        }
    }

    closedir($dh);

    if ($deleteRootToo)
    {
        @rmdir($dir);
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will remove recursively (like `rm -r`). Be careful!

```
function rm_recursive($filepath)
{
    if (is_dir($filepath) && !is_link($filepath))
    {
        if ($dh = opendir($filepath))
        {
            while (($sf = readdir($dh)) !== false)
            {
                if ($sf == '.' || $sf == '..')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!rm_recursive($filepath.'/'.$sf))
                {
                    throw new Exception($filepath.'/'.$sf.' could not be deleted.');
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
        return rmdir($filepath);
    }
    return unlink($filepath);
}
```